# how to create deployable war in spring using maven

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, maven-assembly-plugin

Creating war in spring what are the dependency needed ?
1) maven compiler and maven war plugins are required ?
2) How to add class path reference to war package ?

Answer (score 1):

Create a Maven Spring project and in pom.xml change the packaging to war:

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>Maven Spring Project</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
```

And just build the project using Maven by executing goal : "clean install". It will automatically create war file in target folder of Maven project.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in your pom.xml

```
<build>
        <finalName>projectname</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-compiler-plugin-version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${jdk-version}</source>
                    <target>${jdk-version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-war-plugin-version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.17</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>-XX:-UseSplitVerifier</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

and to make war run this **package tomcat7:run** goal from eclipse